# Website picture to UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, uilabel

I'm new to Xcode so bear with me.

I want to take a picture and text from a website (not the URL for just the picture) and connect it to a UIImageWiev. For example: here's a URL for an ebay item:

http://www.ebay.com/itm/Apple-iPod-touch-4th-Generation-Black-8-GB-ipod-4-/300858009687?pt=Other_MP3_Players&hash=item460c88e857

Let's say I would like to take the picture showing the item and add it to a UIImageView, and take the title (Apple iPod touch 4th Generation Black (8 GB) ipod 4) and add that to a Label. How would I do that?

The URL for the image can be found in the source code of the page, but I don't know how to access it and to extract just the URL for the picture.

I'd like to be able to do this with any ebay item.

Hope you understand my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://img.abc.com/noPhoto4530.gif"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
```

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work. I don't know if you understood my question. The URL I have is NOT for the picture itself, but to a website which has the picture embedded. So I need to fetch the URL for the picture from the websites source code or something.

Comment: user2059738, if you don't have a link to the image, you should parse your web page.